# wireless connection error

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I just installed fresh ubuntu 20.04 i updated the proprietary driver under the additional software app it shows it uses the driver. when i am connected with ethernet it shows the wifi is connected but when i disconnect the ethernet under wifi it shows hardware stopped and i can even turn it on. If i restart there's no option of wifi available

Comment: If you reboot with the ethernet cable UNplugged, are you able to see afailable Wi-Fi networks? (using icons at top RHS)

Comment: no there is no wifi sign even if i restart without the ethernet plugged in